# How to group a list by a value?

Tags: kotlin

I have a list and I want to make an object of all the values that contain a certain id.

```
val list = listOf(A(id = 1), A(1), A(2), A(3), A(2))
```

From that list I want to make a new list of type `Container`

```
data class Container(
   val id: Long // The id passed into A.
   val elementList: List<A> // The elements that contain the ID.
)
```

How can I do this in an efficient way without going O(n^2)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `groupBy` + `map`.
The implementation of `groupBy` is *O(n)* and the implementation of `map` is *O(n)* so the total runtime is *O(2n)* which is *O(n)*.

```kotlin
list.groupBy { it.id }.map { (id, elementList) -> Container(id, elementList) }
```

Since this is so short and readable, I'd avoid to make further optimizations if not strictly needed but, if you'd need some further optimizations, you can reduce also the space cost avoiding to allocate multiple lists for example.

Comment: Fantastic answer! Thank you!